# Why is the constructor to the object called before key check for map::emplace

Tags: c++, c++11

Having the code like this:

```
class HugeConstructor
{
public:
  HugeConstructor(int n)
  {
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, HugeConstructor> m;
    m.emplace(1, 10);
    m.emplace(1, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect to have a single output of `10`, but i get two of them. This means that the object is being constructed, despite the fact that it is actually not going to be needed at all.

Is there a reason for that at all? This seems to be very counter-intuitive.

I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4, compiling with `g++ -c -Wall -std=c++11 -lpthread`

Comment: What toolchain are you using?

Comment: @Cameron g++ with C++11 option set

Comment: Because what you pass to `emplace` is the arguments to the constructor of `value_type`, i.e., `pair`. It's kinda hard to get the key out of the pair without constructing one, especially due to `piecewise_construct` (even if you somehow special-case this, you can only construct the key from the arguments once, and it isn't required to be movable). [`try_emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) fixes this for C++17.

Comment: The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) could be improved, `Inserts a new element into the container by constructing it in-place with the given args if there is no element with the key in the container. ` makes it sound like it only constructs the object if there is no duplicate key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath the hood, maps are implemented as red-black trees. This is true for libc++ and libstdc++ for example. The element needs to be constructed in order to find its parent in the tree:

`libstdc++`:

```
 1613       _M_emplace_unique(_Args&&... __args)
 1614       {
 1615     _Link_type __z = _M_create_node(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
 1616 
 1617     __try
 1618       {
 1619         typedef pair<iterator, bool> _Res;
 1620         auto __res = _M_get_insert_unique_pos(_S_key(__z));
 1621         if (__res.second)
 1622           return _Res(_M_insert_node(__res.first, __res.second, __z),
```

`libc++`:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Allocator>
pair<typename __tree<_Tp, _Compare, _Allocator>::iterator, bool>
__tree<_Tp, _Compare, _Allocator>::__node_insert_unique(__node_pointer __nd)
{
    __node_base_pointer __parent;
    __node_base_pointer& __child = __find_equal(__parent, __nd->__value_);
    __node_pointer __r = static_cast<__node_pointer>(__child);
    bool __inserted = false;
    if (__child == nullptr)
    {
        __insert_node_at(__parent, __child, static_cast<__node_base_pointer>(__nd));
```